# There is an image embedded on my page that I can't locate in order to delete. Please help me!

Tags: images

This is what the page looks like on the site (once published):

[image]

This is what it looks like when I go to edit the page. The image isn't there (it's positioned above the text you'll see here) and can't be selected or deleted, and I can't find it through any other means:

[image]

Comment: please ask in your theme's support forum at https://wordpress.org/support/theme/simplus-blog

Answer (score 0):

That's the featured image for that page.  If you look at your page editor, to the right you have *Permalink*, *Featured Image*, *Discussion*, *Page Attributes*, and *Hide Title?*

You want to expand the *'Featured Image'* one and click *'Remove'*.

What you've done is assign what I assume is your logo as the featured image to your page and the theme then places it immediately at the top of the entry content.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this addresses your issue, please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: I don't see how to 'accept' the answer. No such visible button/option.

Comment: On my Answer, there is arrows point up and down and then beneath them a checkmark.  If you click it, it should turn green.  :-)